# php offset 0 のときのview表示を0にしたい。

Tags: php

エラー表示
`Notice (8): Undefined offset: 0 [APP/View/posts/index.ctp, line 92]`
のときに0を表示させたいのですが、
以下のコードのときにoffset 0の表示がでます。

```
<?php
  $rate = ($one[0]['Post']['id_count'] / $two[0]['Post']['id_count'])*100;
     if ($rate == null) {
         echo "0";
     } else {
         print round($rate,1);
     } 
?>
```

上記の記述で、offset 0 のときに0を表示させて、数字があるときにはその値を表示させたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ここでいう offset は、 `$one[0]` や `$two[0]` の `[]` の中に指定した数字のことで、日本語では添字などと言います。配列に添字0の要素がなかったというエラーですから、おそらくどちらかの配列が空だったのでしょう。

`$rate = ...` の行でエラーが起きているので、**それよりも前に** `$one` と `$two` の状態を確認して、もしどちらかが空だったら `$one[0]` や `$two[0]` を実行しないようにする必要があります。

```
<?php
     if (empty($one) || empty($two)) {
         echo "0";
     } else {
         $rate = ($one[0]['Post']['id_count'] / $two[0]['Post']['id_count'])*100;
         print round($rate,1);
     } 
?>
```

上記コードでは [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.empty.php) を使いましたが、`$one === []` 、`!isset($one[0])` 、 `count($one) === 0` といった方法でも同じような判定が行えます。